# ActionMailer not working after upgrade Rails & Ruby version. Only works in terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just upgraded my app from Rails 4.0 to 4.2.6 and our Ruby version to 2.3.7.

As I am testing my app, I am noticing my reset password emails are NOT being sent out. Take a look.

> **password_resets_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  if @user
    @user.deliver_password_reset_instructions!
  end
  flash[:notice] = "Instructions to reset your password have been emailed to you"
  render :action => :new
end
```

This `deliver_password_reset_instructions!` exists in my **User** model file.

> **user.rb** (hasn't been changed in over a year)

```
def deliver_password_reset_instructions!
  reset_perishable_token! #this method updates the user's perishable_token 
  NotificationMailer.send_reset_instructions(self)
end
```

But... when I call my `send_reset_instructions` method in the NotificationMailer model, nothing happens anymore. However... when I put a debugger in my code, as such:

```
def deliver_password_reset_instructions!
  reset_perishable_token! #this method updates the user's perishable_token 
  binding.pry # If I call `NotificationMailer.send_reset_instructions(self)` it works
  NotificationMailer.send_reset_instructions(self)
end
```

and I run the `NotificationMailer.send_reset_instructions(self)`, it works, but not without me typing it.

It just seems realyl wierd to me that... it works... but only if it I manually type it in the debugger. So, I can't put my finger on WHERE it is broken.

Comment: My advice? Don't jump from Rails 4.0 to 4.2, and from Ruby (whatever you were before) to 2.3.7, blindly, and then be shocked when something stops working. GO one version at a time. Read the [upgrade guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html) -- they're extremely useful. Add tests. (A test should have failed here.) Worst case scenario, you could at least come on StackOverflow and say "when upgrading from Rails **4.1.16** to **4.2.0**, this changed". (Although I'd be shocked if there wasn't already a warning about that in the upgrade guide.)

Comment: We did go incrementally.

Comment: If you're not living life on the edge, you're taking up too much space!

Comment: If you went incrementally, then why do you not know whether it was rails 4.1, or rails 4.2, or some ruby version bump, that caused the issue? You should *test the application thoroughly* after each version bump, especially if you have insufficient test coverage to proceed with confidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActionMailer changed in Rails 4.2, quoting the [upgrade guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.10/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#action-mailer):

> Previously, calling a mailer method on a mailer class will result in the corresponding instance method being executed directly. With the introduction of Active Job and `#deliver_later`, this is no longer true. In Rails 4.2, the invocation of the instance methods are deferred until either `deliver_now` or `deliver_later` is called.

So in your case, simply appending `.deliver_now` to your call should work:

```
NotificationMailer.send_reset_instructions(self).deliver_now
```

Comment: This is working! I am getting 2 emails now, but I think I can take care of that!